# Cordova build fails building Cordova project on Visual Studio team services

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova project build fails while building on Visual Studio team services with the following error:

[image: Cordova Build Error Image]

I am referring to this article [Build and Test Cordova Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vsts/build-release/archive/apps/mobile/cordova-build).

My Cordova version is 6.2.1.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the StackTrace and error message as a text to the question instead of a picture.

Also if possible provide the peace of code where the problem arises.

From first glance the error is explanatory itself. You try to access a directory or file that it not at the specified path.

Comment: @Nico Thanks. I cannot find the piece of code that generates error because there is no file named cordova-task.js in my local project folder and I can build the cordova app locally on android.

Comment: @Nico I have given the correct path to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the problem. Under working directory in Cordova Build Step, I had given path to the .sln file. The correct path that should be given must be to the Cordova project folder(i.e. which contains www, platforms, etc). Also while checking in node_modules folder should not be checked in.